# How to compare strings ignoring the case

Tags: ruby, string, string-comparison

I want `apple` and `Apple` comparison to be `true`.
Currently

```
"Apple" == "Apple"  # returns TRUE
"Apple" == "APPLE"  # returns FALSE
```

Answer (score 301, accepted):

You're looking for [`casecmp`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-casecmp). It returns `0` if two strings are equal, case-insensitively.

```
str1.casecmp(str2) == 0

"Apple".casecmp("APPLE") == 0
#=> true
```

Alternatively, you can convert both strings to lower case ([`str.downcase`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-downcase)) and compare for equality.

Comment: From my benchmarks casecmp is at least twice as fast as the downcase method

Comment: `casecmp`: a silly name for a case- *in* -sensitive compare method?!

Comment: @Zabba: Blame the libc people: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strcasecmp.html

Comment: If you like using words, you can replace the `== 0` with `zero?`

Comment: String also has a `.nonzero?` method, so `str1 != str2` can be made case-insensitive as `str1.casecmp(str2).nonzero?`

Comment: Using #casecmp is better than using #downcase, because the latter doesn't always behave the way a human thinks it should. Eg calling #upcase on the ligature character "ﬄ" returns the character unchanged. 

Source:
https://mortoray.com/2013/11/27/the-string-type-is-broken/

Comment: If you use Rubocop the correct way for it not to complain is `"Apple".casecmp("APPLE").zero?`
But personally I like Andres answer below, which uses `.casecmp?`

Comment: See @andres answer below using .casecmp? for true/false return

Comment: @AndrewGrimm A caveat to that is if either value is `nil` then the result is `nil` so calling `.zero?` on that will raise an error. So `==` is safer. I'd rather have `"apple".casecmp(b) == 0` than `"apple"
.casecmp(b || "").zero?`

Answer (score 60):

In **Ruby 2.4.0** you have: `casecmp?(other_str) → true, false, or nil`

```
"abcdef".casecmp?("abcde")     #=> false
"aBcDeF".casecmp?("abcdef")    #=> true
"abcdef".casecmp?("abcdefg")   #=> false
"abcdef".casecmp?("ABCDEF")    #=> true
```

[Here you have more info](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/String.html#method-i-casecmp-3F)

Comment: A good improvement to the method but this is one of the least "Ruby sounding" methods I've ever seen. Feels like I'm using Java with this `casecmp` junk.

Comment: I'd honestly suggest that you use `"aBcDeF".downcase == "abcdef"` instead. Much more readable and the performance gains of using `casecmp` are eliminated in Ruby 2.4+.

Comment: Wait, what would the difference be between `false` and `nil` for an API like this...

Comment: According to the docs nil is returned when other_str is not a string

Answer (score 9):

In case you have to compare UTF-8 strings ignoring case:

```js
>> str1 = "Мария"
=> "Мария"
>> str2 = "мария"
=> "мария"
>> str1.casecmp(str2) == 0
=> false
>> require 'active_support/all'
=> true
>> str1.mb_chars.downcase.to_s.casecmp(str2.mb_chars.downcase.to_s) == 0
=> true
```

It works this way in Ruby 2.3.1 and earlier versions.

For smaller memory footprint you can cherry pick `string/multibyte`:

```rb
require 'active_support'
require 'active_support/core_ext/string/multibyte'
```

**Edit**, Ruby 2.4.0:

```js
>> str1.casecmp(str2) == 0
=> false
```

So `casecmp` doesn't work in 2.4.0; However in 2.4.0 one can compare UTF-8 strings manually without `active_support` gem:

```js
>> str1.downcase == str2.downcase
=> true
```

Answer (score 7):

For ruby 2.4 working fine [casecmp?](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/String.html#method-i-casecmp-3F) for utf-8 strings (mb_chars not needed):

```rb
2.4.1 :062 > 'строка1'.casecmp?('СтроКа1')
 => true
```

but casecmp isn't workin for utf-8:

```rb
2.4.1 :062 > 'строка1'.casecmp('СтроКА1')
 => 1
2.4.1 :063 > 'string1'.casecmp('StrInG1')
 => 0
```

Answer (score 6):

casecmp and zero? are ruby inbuilt methods. casecmp returns 0 if two strings are equal, case-insensitively and zero? checks for zero value (==0)

```
str1.casecmp(str2).zero?
```

Comment: That's what my style checker told me, and I like it because it's clearer than comparing with literal `0`, especially when nested with a more involved condition.

Comment: as mentioned above, casecmp can return nil which would raise a `NoMethodError` when calling `zero?`