# Apply .capitalize on an Cyrillic array in ruby

Tags: ruby, capitalize

I want to capitalise the string elements in the array with ruby

This is my code:

```
headermonths = ["января","февраля","марта","апреля","мая","июня","июля","августа","октября","ноября","декабря"]

headermonths.each {|month| month.capitalize!}
puts headermonths
```

I get the following output:

```
января
февраля
марта
апреля
мая
июня
июля
августа
октября
ноября
декабря
```

if print the array with:

```
 print headermonths
```

I get the following

`["\u044F\u043D\u0432\u0430\u0440\u044F", "\u0444\u0435\u0432\u0440\u0430\u043B\u044F", "\u043C\u0430\u0440\u0442\u0430", "\u0430\u043F\u0440\u0435\u043B\u044F", "\u043C\u0430\u044F", "\u0438\u044E\u043D\u044F", "\u0438\u044E\u043B\u044F", "\u0430\u0432\u0433\u0443\u0441\u0442\u0430", "\u043E\u043A\u0442\u044F\u0431\u0440\u044F", "\u043D\u043E\u044F\u0431\u0440\u044F", "\u0434\u0435\u043A\u0430\u0431\u0440\u044F"]`

But I would like to have an output like:

`Января
Февраля
Марта
Апреля
Мая
Июня
Июля
Августа
Октября
Ноября
Декабря`

How does I achieve this with a ruby method?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35102312/788700

Comment: Your code just works as is on Ruby 2.4, which is going to be released in two days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [unicode gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/unicode/versions/0.4.4.2)

```
require 'unicode'

headermonths = ["января","февраля","марта","апреля","мая","июня","июля","августа","октября","ноября","декабря"]

headermonths.map! {|month| Unicode::capitalize month }
puts headermonths
# >> ["Января", "Февраля", "Марта", "Апреля", "Мая", "Июня", "Июля", "Августа", "Октября", "Ноября", "Декабря"]
```

Answer (score 2):

## Stand-alone solution :

```
# From : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyrillic_alphabets :
upcase   = "АБВГДЕЖЗИЙКЛМНОПРСТУФХЦЧШЩЬЮЯ"
downcase = "абвгдежзийклмнопрстуфхцчшщьюя"

headermonths = ["января","февраля","марта","апреля","мая","июня","июля","августа","октября","ноября","декабря"]

headermonths.each{|word| word[0] = word[0].tr(downcase,upcase)}
# => ["Января", "Февраля", "Марта", "Апреля", "Мая", "Июня", "Июля", "Августа", "Октября", "Ноября", "Декабря"]
```

If you want to use it with words in latin and cyrillic alphabets :

```
headermonths.each{|word| word[0] = word[0].tr(downcase,upcase).upcase }
```

## With ActiveSupport

You can use [ActiveSupport::Multibyte](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Multibyte/Chars.html) :

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/string/multibyte'
"января".mb_chars.capitalize.to_s #=> "Января"
```

So your script becomes :

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/string/multibyte'

headermonths = ["января","февраля","марта","апреля","мая","июня","июля","августа","октября","ноября","декабря"]

headermonths.map!{|word| word.mb_chars.capitalize.to_s}
#=> ["Января", "Февраля", "Марта", "Апреля", "Мая", "Июня", "Июля", "Августа", "Октября", "Ноября", "Декабря"]
```

## Ruby 2.4

The code in your question would work just as expected with Ruby 2.4.

See "Case sensitivity for unicode characters" [here](https://blog.blockscore.com/new-features-in-ruby-2-4/).

Comment: What exactly here depends on Ruby 2.4?

Comment: I said that *his* code would work just fine with Ruby 2.4. See "Case sensitivity for unicode characters" in the above link.

Comment: Ah, right, yes, indeed. `pack` is still sexier, though :)

Answer (score 1):

The example below is a robust capitalize version, that works in any ruby starting with 1.9 *but for cyrillic only due to `-32` hardcoded*.

**NB**: thanks and credits go to @Stefan and @EricDuminil, who lead me to the right direction

```
headermonths = %w|января февраля марта апреля мая июня
                  июля августа октября ноября декабря|
puts (headermonths.each do |s|
  s[0] = (s[0].ord - 32).chr(Encoding::UTF_8) 
end.inspect)
#⇒ ["Января", "Февраля", "Марта", "Апреля", "Мая", "Июня",
#   "Июля", "Августа", "Октября", "Ноября", "Декабря"]
```

Comment: I guess `(s[0].ord - 32).chr + s[1..-1]` would be too simple? ;-)

Comment: @Stefan it won’t work raising `\`chr': 1071 out of char range (RangeError)` for `"я"` in `"январь"` and so forth. For Ruby < 2.4, I guess.

Comment: My fault, that should have been `chr(Encoding::UTF_8)`.

Comment: `s[0] = (s[0].ord-32).chr(Encoding::UTF_8)` would also work, and suit `capitalize!` better.

Comment: Your code displays `#<Enumerator:0x00000001560cb0>` by the way. You need `{}` instead of `do end`.